# Vertical page flip effect

Tags: looking-for-a-script, javascript, html5, jquery, plugin

I found [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/) as a very simple and nice effect to create page flip effect. The problem is that I'm looking for that effect but vertical not horizontal.

Does anybody knows any Javascript or what should I modify in that one to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: I would think modifying the code effectively swapping `x` and `y` (well it's probably a bit more complicated than that) would be the easiest solution. Give it a go and if you get stuck ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @ChrisF I already tried to modify the code, and all I get is to enable the bottom corners for next page and top corners for previous page.. but the `x` `y` swapping is not as easy as it might look.. :)

Comment: I was afraid of that. Stack Overflow might be your best bet for solving those, but break the problem down into small chunks.

Comment: Ok.. I'll do that.. in the meantime I'll leave this question open in case somebody find an script for the vertical effect.. Thanks

Comment: Did you find any workaround to use Turn.js for vertical flips? Did you try rotating the entire view by 90 degrees?

Comment: @njs I didn't test that, but I guess that wouldn't work as everything will be rotated (text, images..)

Answer (score 2):

This script has vertical flipping Homepage http://pageflip.hu/, and vertical flip demo http://pageflip.hu/demo_vertical.html

Comment: That's a great example, but it was made with Flash.. Also I love the hard cover effect.. upvoted for the link :)

Comment: Didn't know it was flash, it was linked from a page going to a bunch of flipping scripts must have had both jquery and flash listed.

Comment: I have an updated version of my script at http://pageflip-books.com (moved from pageflip.hu), with a html5 version, which also supports vertical flipping.